# Datagrid displaying as an empty datagrid. Even headers not showing

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I was trying to create a suggestion list. Which means when I type barcode, all barcodes starting with what I typed should be displayed in another data grid.
   The data grid display is correct row counts but not the contents even header isn't displaying.

I have tried creating a Datagrid with 6 columns and wrote code to display Datagrid in TextChanged Property of barcode textbox.

My XAML Part:

```
 <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10">
                    <DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False"  Visibility="Hidden" Style="{StaticResource DataGridListing}" x:Name="DataGridSalesSuggestion" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}, Mode=FindAncestor}}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}, Mode=FindAncestor}}">

                        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Width="1*" Header="{Binding barcode, Source={StaticResource Strings}}" x:Name="DataGridSuggestionItemName"  Binding="{Binding BarCode}"  />
                        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Width="1*" Header="{Binding ItemCode, Source={StaticResource Strings}}" x:Name="DataGridSuggestionItemCode"  Binding="{Binding ItemCode}"  />
                        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Width="1*" Header="{Binding itemName, Source={StaticResource Strings}}" x:Name="DataGridSuggestionBarcode"   Binding="{Binding ItemName}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Width="1*" Header="{Binding UnitQuantity, Source={StaticResource Strings}}" x:Name="DataGridSuggestionUnitQty"  Binding="{Binding UnitQuantity}"  />
                        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Width="1*" Header="{Binding price, Source={StaticResource Strings}}" x:Name="DataGridColumnSuggestionPrice"  Binding="{Binding PricePerUnit}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Width="1*" Header="{Binding StockQty, Source={StaticResource Strings}}" x:Name="DataGridColumnSuggestionStockQty"  Binding="{Binding StockQuantity}" />

                    </DataGrid>
                </Grid>
```

Code-Behind:

```
private void TextboxBarCodeTextchanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Stock obj = DataGridSalesDetails.SelectedItem as Stock;


        DataGridSalesSuggestion.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < AllStockList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.BarCode))
            {
                if (AllStockList[i].BarCode.StartsWith(obj.BarCode, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {

                    Stock vend = AllStockList[i] as Stock;
                    DataGridSalesSuggestion.Items.Add(vend);
                    DataGridSalesSuggestion.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
            }
        }
        if (DataGridSalesSuggestion.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            DataGridSalesSuggestion.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.BarCode))
        {
            DataGridSalesSuggestion.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

Expected Result is this Datagrid should display the contents related to what I type in barcode textbox.

Actual Result is this code getting is showing an empty Datagrid. even header is not displaying. Can anyone help? Am new to .net

Comment: As a note, binding a child element's size to that of its parent (like `Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}, Mode=FindAncestor}}"`) is entirely pointless. A Grid already resizes its child elements.

Comment: Besides that, instead of directly adding elements to the Items collection of the DataGrid, you should assign or bind its ItemsSource property to a collection of data item objects.

Comment: Also make sure that thinks like `ItemCode` in your `Strings` resource object are public properties.

Comment: @Clemens, Ofcourse ItemCode is a public object.

Comment: @Clemens, And this is not an observable collection. It automatically adds one by one to the object Vend. So how could i bind it with itemssource?

Comment: What is a "public object"? Just make sure they are public properties, not public fields. For the other point, use an ObservableCollection for the ItemsSource and add elements to that collection.

Comment: I got the answer. The properties were public.But I didn't make them `INotifyPropertyChanged`. That's why I had the empty rows.